# How to group and sum data based on dynamic where condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How to group and sum data based on dynamic where condition? I have to sum rows based on given dates. I have different dates that will passed as a parameter and have to sum item cost.

Example

[image]

Given above image from table without summing item_cost. Here I have to sum item_cost field based on bill_date field. Dates can vary which will be taken from another table and have to sum.

Below is query I have to used to get all item cost with summing

```
SELECT item_cost, 
       bill_date 
FROM billing 
WHERE (bill_date <= "2022-03-30 13:00:00" || bill_date <= "2022-03-30 18:00:00")
```

Here I have to group and sum item_cost based on given date. Sum of item_cost of bill_date <= "2022-03-30 13:00:00" and in another row bill_date <= "2022-03-30 18:00:00"

Comment: Please, can you provide your data as TEXT, next time you ask a question ?   I know that [PowerToys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/text-extractor) has a nice TextExtractor which can do some OCR, but simply copying/pasting text is sooooo much easier..... 

Answer (score 0):

This will give both totals:

```sql
SELECT 
  second.d, 
  sum(CASE WHEN bill_date<=second.d THEN item_cost END) as SUM
FROM billing
CROSS JOIN second
GROUP BY second.d
ORDER BY second.d
```

output:

| d | SUM |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-30 13:00:00 | 102333.69 |
| 2022-03-30 18:00:00 | 218490.36 |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/fR7XD-fa)